# How to cast the Average layer output to push it into a Conv2D layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, typeerror, convolution

I am trying to build a custom CNN using keras functional API. The issue with my **theoretical** idea and **pratical** one is that when I try to Average the ouput of three Conv2D layers and pass it to another Conv2D. I get an error saying that the output of Average is `tf.float` meanwhile Conv2D (that is the first convolution layer of VGG16, because I am doing transfer learning) expects to get a `tf.int32`

I am getting the follwing error: `**TypeError: Expected int32, got 0.0 of type 'float' instead.`

**Notes:**

1. I have tried Maximum and Minimum as a test only and still getting the same error.
2. Unfortunetly I can't share the code because of NDA.

Here's a code snippet:

```
self._layer_hs_o = Average(name="heads")(
      [self._layer_hs_s, self._layer_hs_m, self._layer_hs_l])
# Trying to pass the average output to the following Conv2D layer
self._layer_d2c_c = Conv2D(d2c_config["filters"], 
      d2c_config["kernels"][0], 
      padding="same",
      activation=d2c_config["activation"], 
      name="d2c_c",
      kernel_initializer=d2c_config["init"],
      input_shape=self._layer_hs_o.shape,
      dilation_rate=d2c_config["dilations"][0]
    )(self._layer_hs_o)
```

At this moment the model can't be compiled because of this step. When I skip it to normal convolutions only it get compiled and the learning happens normally. Yet I need to use the Average layer at some extent.

Comment: Please add reproducible code.

Comment: @M.Innat Sadly, I can't add reproducible code because the project that I am working on requires non disclosure agreement. I am bound to some legal concerns.

Comment: No, I didn't want you to do that. I simply requested to give some reproducible code (with some dummy data). FYI, while averaging the output of the layer, I think you can change the type of average layer to `int`.

Comment: We cannot help you unless you share some code that reproduces or shows the problem, as this error makes no sense to me.

Comment: @M.Innat I've added a snippet of my code please check it. Thank you for your help in advance.